# How to get data in between time intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here is my table

```
T_idx          T_Tag         T_Date  
1              x             2014-03-15 23:58:00.000
2              y             2014-03-15 23:57:00.000
.               .                  .
.
.               .                  .
.
555            xy            2014-03-15 5:10:00.000
```

From the above table,  I want to see the data in between 5:30 AM to 6:30 AM every day

Could you please any one suggest me the query to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way in SQL Server 2005:

```
select * from mytable 
where convert(datetime, convert(char(5), T_Date, 108)) >= '5:30'
and convert(datetime, convert(char(5), T_Date, 108)) <= '6:30'
```

In SQL Server 2008 and above, you can simply cast it to `time` data type:

```
select * from mytable 
where convert(time, T_Date) >= '5:30'
and convert(time, T_Date) <= '6:30'
```

Comment: created '.Bat' by using above code and running schedule task (Control panel) everyday but the file running continuously even after execution of result. Please find the below code in the bat file                                              sqlcmd -q "Select top 1000 from my table where convert(datetime, convert(char(5), T_Date, 108)) >= '5:30'
and convert(datetime, convert(char(5), T_Date, 108)) <= '6:30' order by T_Date DESC" -oF:\export\export.txt -h-1-s";" exit                                   i need to stop ".BAT" file execution after completion of above task, help me to stop in auto

Comment: @venkat Did it select the records correctly? On Stack Overflow, you should ask one problem in one question. You will be better off to create a new question for your .bat file problem.

Comment: yes it did it correctly !!!! thank you very much !!! i will create a new question for .BAT file problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SET @start_date = DATEADD(minutes,30,DATEADD(hour, 5, DATEDIFF(DAY, 2, GETDATE())))
SET @end_date = DATEADD(hour, -1, @start_date)

SELECT 
    T_idx, T_Tag
FROM 
    YourTable
WHERE
    T_Date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
```